# MSChart HitResult AxisLabel

Tags: c#, charts, click

Using MS Chart component in C# and trying to determine the item hit (HitResult). It seems that the result is not always accurate. If I have two charts. Right hand side is always a column chart. Left hand side is sometimes a column chart and sometimes a doughnut. The Item returned from HitResult when left hand side is a Doughnut is not correct. Image of what I mean :

[image]

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend legend1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint dataPoint1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint(0D, 10D);
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint dataPoint2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint(0D, 20D);
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea chartArea2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend legend2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint dataPoint3 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint(0D, 10D);
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint dataPoint4 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint(0D, 20D);
            this.chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
            this.chart2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart2)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // chart1
            // 
            chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
            this.chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
            legend1.Name = "Legend1";
            this.chart1.Legends.Add(legend1);
            this.chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
            this.chart1.Name = "chart1";
            series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
            series1.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Doughnut;
            series1.Label = "bbb";
            series1.Legend = "Legend1";
            series1.Name = "Series1";
            dataPoint1.AxisLabel = "AAA";
            dataPoint2.AxisLabel = "BBB";
            dataPoint2.Label = "aaa";
            series1.Points.Add(dataPoint1);
            series1.Points.Add(dataPoint2);
            this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);
            this.chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
            this.chart1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.chart1.Text = "chart1";
            this.chart1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.chart1_MouseDown);
            // 
            // chart2
            // 
            chartArea2.Name = "ChartArea1";
            this.chart2.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea2);
            legend2.Name = "Legend1";
            this.chart2.Legends.Add(legend2);
            this.chart2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(341, 13);
            this.chart2.Name = "chart2";
            series2.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
            series2.Legend = "Legend1";
            series2.Name = "Series1";
            dataPoint3.AxisLabel = "111";
            dataPoint4.AxisLabel = "2222";
            series2.Points.Add(dataPoint3);
            series2.Points.Add(dataPoint4);
            this.chart2.Series.Add(series2);
            this.chart2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
            this.chart2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.chart2.Text = "chart2";
            this.chart2.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.chart1_MouseDown);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(801, 490);
            this.Controls.Add(this.chart2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.chart1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart2)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two independent Charts, right? By default each already comes with a ChartArea. No need to add one more, unless you want to show the two charts in one Chart control with two Chartareas. You seem to be  mixing things up. Do not add a second ChartArea unless you really want two! Since you don't show the __Two__  MosueClick&HitTest events we can only guess. Maybe you only have one?? But with two Chart controls that makes no sense.. Show us more code, especially __how you switch the charttypes__!

Comment: I need two charts as opposed to two chartAreas as the charts are of different ChartTypes. I switch the code - manually by editing the line which defines the charttype for the left hand side and re-running.  The full code is above and the complete project can be downloaded from [link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByfxXBQPP7odOXdGVGFpdDB4Rk0)

Comment: You can easily have different ChartTypes in two ChartAreas of the same Chart control. Even in the same ChartArea if the Types are compatible. Pie is not, but there is no need for a 2nd Chart. No problem either, though.. - Did you really mean that you change the Designer.CS file to change the charttypes??? Ouch! Why not simply do it in code, maybe a button click??? someSeries.ChartType= ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Designer code the problem is easily found: **You hook up the very same event to two different** `Chart` controls.

This is actually a common way to avoid redundant code; the trick is to cast the `sender` to the right control type and then use the result.

So you probably do a hit test with the wrong Chart; you still don't show the `MouseClick or MouseDown` code but most likely it contains something like this:

```
HitTestResult hitr = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
```

What you would need, if you really want to use only one event is this:

```
HitTestResult hitr = ((Chart)sender).HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
```

---

As I have explained in my comments above, there is really not need to have two `Chart` controls in the first place; add an extra `ChartArea` and assign the series you want to show in it the name:

```
ChartArea ca2 = chart1.ChartAreas.Add("ca2");
series1.ChartArea = "ca2";
```

You can switch between `ChartTypes` dynamically, maybe with a `CheckBox`:

```
series1.ChartType = cbx_Pie.Checked ? SeriesChartType.Pie : SeriesChartType.Column;
```

Using **two** (or more) `ChartAreas` in one `Chart` has a few advantages. Not only will they shar a `BorderStyle` and `Background`; they will also both draw onto the same `Bitmap` with `DrawToBitmap` and they will **scale** together when **resizing** the `Chart. But this is your design..

Comment: Thanks so much. As you identified the problem was the event handler in that I was not using Sender. Once again, thanks